# Запуск программ от имени администратора через батник

Tags: windows, cmd, bat, uac

Есть batch-скрипт, который выполняет некие действия с файлами и каталогами, попутно запуская несколько экзешников с определенными параметрами. Все работает, но каждый раз при вызове экзешника всплывает окно UAC. В результате теряется весь смысл автоматизации: я вынужден сидеть и прожимать "Да" в окошках UAC, вместо того, чтобы пойти пить чай, например. Есть ли способ запустить программу через скрипт сразу с нужными правами? Пробовал запускать сам скрипт от имени администратора, но он при этом перестает корректно работать.

Answer (score 3):

Существует много различных вариантов запуска приложения без подтверждения UAC, самое простое - это можно отключить UAC полностью, что крайне не рекомендуется.
Так же можно добавить в реестр запись, чтобы запускалась определённая программа с повышенными правами без запроса UAC:
Создайте файл с любым именем, расширение файла .reg (file1.reg), поместите в файла информацию, которую нужно внести в реестр:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"C:\\Windows\\regedit.exe"="RUNASINVOKER"
```

Обязательно замените путь к файлу на свой скрипт.
Выполните скрипт один раз от имени администратора.
Данный скрипт будет запускаться без подтверждение UAC только в случае, если он будет находится по указаному пути, который вы внесли в реестр.